# CSS Image Background - Same Scale Across Different Devices

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website with possible multiple fluid background sections that are consistent in scale between mobile, tablet and desktop (including different resolutions). The background is to stay in the centre to cover the whole area and appears in the same scale across all device types.

Things I tried are: `background-position: cover` Does stretch but scales with the monitor width resulting in the image moving.

And created a background wrapper with a inner part with a fixed width of say around 1920 pixels across. The height will be fixed.

The one that works best at this time is the background inside a wrapper with a specified width.

https://jsfiddle.net/dy6ab36y/

HTML:

```
<div class="background-wrapper">
  <div class="background-inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-wrapper {
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.background-inner {
 width: 1920px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -960px;
 position: absolute;
 height: 250px;
 display: block;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there more efficient way of working around this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dy6ab36y/8/ ?

Comment: The only reason this works for you is because you have a fixed size on your inner box, so `background-size: cover` becomes irrelevant (because your inner box isn't fluid). You might as well define your `background-size` as `1920px auto` and be done with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-size `cover` is only useful if you want to stretch your `background-image`. If you are going to put it in a fixed-size container anyway, there no point to doing what you are doing anyhow. The best solution might simple be to define a `background-size` in a non-relative unit, like `px`.

So the solution is to fix the width in a manner like this:

```css
.background-wrapper {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-image: url(https://psuk.s3.amazonaws.com/asset/p4/image/c3c59e5f8b3e9753913f4d435b53c308/Shaun/3040ce690fce2054c2011cf6d2f8b537.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    /* By defining this, your image _will_ be cut off when the screen is
     * wider than 1920px, but since you don't want to stretch this would
     *  happen anyway. */
    background-size: 1920px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, although this does not actually fit the requirement you commented to @MustafaSabur : 'It is a requirement it needs to stretch to the device width.' - this won't. If you need something thats fixed width and increases only once it needs to cover more space than available, your solution combined with a `min-width` inner box is the only way to accomplish that (`min-width: 1920px; width: 100%; background-size: 100% auto;`)...

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="background-inner">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-inner {
    height: 250px;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://psuk.s3.amazonaws.com/asset/p4/image/c3c59e5f8b3e9753913f4d435b53c308/Shaun/3040ce690fce2054c2011cf6d2f8b537.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dy6ab36y/8/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a fixed image height or some percentage of the total window height?
Do you want to stretch the background image or not?

if not you could use

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: It is a requirement it needs to stretch to the device width.